# Rails gem for adding text/images to site which retain the language syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, text-editor

I want to make a **blogging site**. So basically, the blogs will contain **posts of code snippets and other coding related stuffs**.

So only the side admin can add posts to his blog. As he will be writing code snippets, I want to **add a text-editor to rails app which will post the code with it syntax,highlight it** and not just as a plain text.

Something like this:

[image]

OR

[image]

It should support all major languages like C,C++,Ruby, Rails,Python.

Suggest a method/gem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ace Editor](http://ace.c9.io/) is good for syntax highlighting and an editor. is pretty good. It is what github uses for gists and things.

For just syntax highlighting, you have many options such as [pygments.rb](https://github.com/tmm1/pygments.rb), [coderay](https://github.com/rubychan/coderay), and [rainbow](https://github.com/ccampbell/rainbow) just to list a few..